# Ruby HERE-DOC method parameter passing

Tags: ruby, heredoc

I am trying to use a custom method with here-doc and want to pass parameter (there is no business case, I am merely trying to learn ruby). Is there a way to pass parameter in this case?  This is what I have so far.

Simple method, just works fine.

```
def meth1
  self.upcase
end

str1 = <<MY.meth1
  i am a small case string
MY

# "I AM A SMALL CASE STRING\n"
```

Now, I thought let us drop some parameters and tried different variations and irb gives me a blank stare.

```
#variation 1

def meth2( <<EOF1, <<EOF2 )
  EOF1.upcase + "..." + EOF2.downcase
end

str2 = <<MY.meth2
 some string
EOF1
 ANOTHER STRING
EOF2
MY
```

Comment: Whats with the `<<` ?

Comment: I don't think you can pass a here doc as an argument. It does not make sense to do that.

Comment: @kevin: I tried EOF1, EOF2 without << as well. As I said, this was one of the different things I tried.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

My guess is that this is what you are trying to do:

```
def meth2(str1, str2)
  str1.upcase + "..." + str2.downcase
end

str2 = meth2(<<EOF1, <<EOF2)
 some string
EOF1
 ANOTHER STRING
EOF2

str2 # => " SOME STRING\n... another string\n"
```

If you don't intent to indent, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3772864). ← See my play with words here?

Comment: this is very close. Accepted

Comment: Still not what you want? How is it different?

Answer (score 3):

try something along the lines of

```
something = "bananas"

str = <<EOF
  this has some #{something} in!
EOF
```

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
def meth2( item1, item2 )
  item1.upcase + "..." + item2.downcase
end

str2 = meth2 <<EOF1, <<EOF2
 some string
EOF1
 ANOTHER STRING
EOF2
```

The problem you are having is due to not fully understanding how heredoc-style string literals work. The `<<DELIMITER` part just is telling the parser to get it's string data from the lines that follow it. If there is more than one `<<DELIMITER` on a line, then they stack, and are read in in sequence. So, in this case, the code above is exactly equivalent to:

```
def meth2( item1, item2 )
  item1.upcase + "..." + item2.downcase
end

str2 = meth2 " some string\n", " ANOTHER STRING\n"
```

Most importantly, there is no way to build a heredoc into a function like you were trying to do there... They can only be used in the same places and manner that other String literals, such as "double quoted" or 'single quoted' literals, can be used.