# How to separate a heredoc from other key-value pairs in a hash literal in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, hashmap, literals, heredoc

I just wanted to use a heredoc as a value in a hash literal. While it works fine if the heredoc is the very last element:

```
{
  foo: 123,
  bar: <<-HEREDOC
    a longer text
  HEREDOC
}
#=> {:foo=>123, :bar=>"    a longer text\n"}
```

I couldn't find a way to add another key-value pair *after* the heredoc. Or, more specifically, I couldn't find a way to insert the separating comma without causing a syntax error:

```
{
  foo: 123,
  bar: <<-HEREDOC
    a longer text
  HEREDOC
  # <- causes a syntax error because a comma is missing here, but where to put it?
  baz: 456
}
```

Comment: you might need to remove leading whitespace as well - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3772864/how-do-i-remove-leading-whitespace-chars-from-ruby-heredoc

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This seems to work

```
{
  foo: 123,
  bar: <<-HEREDOC,
    a longer text
  HEREDOC
  baz: 456
}
```

Comment: Good one! Could you, Stefan or anyone else explain why this works?

Comment: This is so unintuitive but thank you for saving me more time dealing with this issue.

Answer (score 5):

[Ursus' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40320516/477037) is spot on. The reason *why* this works is that the heredoc doesn't start immediately after the opening identifier, but on the line *following* the opening identifier. Everything after the opening identifier (on the same line) is parsed as usual.

This not only allows you to put the `,` right after the `<<-HEREDOC`, it allows you to define the entire hash in one line:

```
{ foo: 123, bar: <<-HEREDOC, baz: 456 }
  a longer text
HEREDOC
#=> {:foo=>123, :bar=>"      a longer text\n", :baz=>456}
```

You could also pass two heredocs: (using `~` instead of `-` strips whitespace)

```
{ foo: 123, bar: <<~BAR, baz: <<~BAZ }
  bar's value
BAR
  baz's value
BAZ
#=> {:foo=>123, :bar=>"bar's value\n", :baz=>"baz's value\n"}
```

Ruby's [heredoc documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Here+Documents) contains similar examples, but unfortunately RDoc doesn't get it right, so they are often overlooked:

> To call a method on a heredoc place it after the opening identifier:
>
> ```
> expected_result = <<-EXPECTED.chomp
> One plus one is #{1 + 1}  
> EXPECTED
> ```
>
> You may open multiple heredocs on the same line, but this can be
>   difficult to read:
>
> ```
>  puts(<<-ONE, <<-TWO)
>  content for heredoc one
>  ONE
>  content for
>  heredoc two
>  TWO
> ```